# Django Choice Field HTML Custom Output

Tags: html, css, django

I'm currently working on a Django project and I'm facing a bit of headache. I need to "convert" an `HTML` page (form) to a proper functioning Django Form App. The problem comes exactly in the ChoiceField (the two choices `Manhã` and `Tarde`). On the left, it's the Django Form `HTML` output and on the right, there's the original `HTML` page. The styling is different and I can't figure out how I can make them equal. Also, I wanted to make them horizontally aligned, but Django it's not so flexible as I thought in this matter.

I hope you can give me clear tips and light in this strange darkness, I have a couple of frontend skills but nothing above the average.

[image]

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You could you use something like bootstrap.

Put both choices in a row (read bootstrap grid documentation). Also, could use bootstrap styling to change the appearance of choice field.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Could also use Django Crispy forms, there's tutorials online on how to use it.